# Travelling between meta and main

Tags: discussion, support, top-bar, navigation

So it took me a while, but I finally figured out how to get from the main site to the meta site using the new toolbar: one first clicks on help, and then the meta button appears. However, I am yet to find out how to get from meta to main using this tool bar. Any hints?

Comment: A little convoluted way: I click on my gravatar at the top, so that I get on my profile page. (In your case you get [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/10513/user1729).) Then I can click on *main user*. (Or, if I start on meta, I can click on *meta user*.) In this way I can also check whether there are some responses that I have forgotten about.

Comment: I have added ([meta-tag:top-bar]) tag, feel free to remove it, if you think it is not suitable for this question. I also think that this should be ([meta-tag:support]) and not ([meta-tag:bug]); but I leave this for the OP to decide. (I thought that changing ([meta-tag:bug]) would be too radical change, so I did not edit this.)

Comment: Yeah, that was the convoluted way I have been using too! I am sure that there used to be a meta button at the very bottom of the page also...

Comment: Also, I put in (bug) just because I was beginning to wonder if such a button did exist...(if it didn't: bug!).

Comment: glad it's not just me who has this problem!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the StackExchange dropdown menu on the far left of the toolbar you will finds links to main and meta (regardless of where you're at). It took me a while to find them too.

Comment: Ah, that button is quite good. It even links to each of the other sites I am a member of! Dunno why I never clicked there. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That little triangle beside it means it is a menu.  Look for that clue elsewhere, too.